# How to extract ticker name from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have following data which is converted in a pandas DataFrame (below lines are a direct copy paste since I do not know how to import it otherwise).

```
{17: '200 shares ExD 2022-09-21 PD 2022-09-30 dividend GAIN.NASDAQ 15.00 USD (0.075 per share) tax -2.25 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06',
18: '101 shares ExD 2022-09-21 PD 2022-09-30 dividend LTC.NYSE 19.19 USD (0.19 per share) tax -2.88 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06',    
19: '302 shares ExD 2022-09-29 PD 2022-10-12 dividend AGNC.NASDAQ 36.24 USD (0.12 per share) tax -5.44 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06',     
20: '92 shares ExD 2022-07-07 PD 2022-08-22 dividend BTI.NYSE 60.31 USD (0.655523 per share) tax -0.00 USD (-0.0%) DivCntry GB fee amount -0.46 USD (0.005 per share)',     
21: '75 shares ExD 2022-09-14 PD 2022-10-11 dividend MO.NYSE 70.50 USD (0.94 per share) tax -10.58 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06'}
```

I need a code to extract just the ticker name from this. My lines are below, but it collects the entire description again. Is there a way to code this so the result would only contain tickers (e.g. `GAIN.NASDAQ, LTC.NYSE, AGNC.NASDAQ, BTI.NYSE, MO.NYSE`)?

```
import pandas as pd
....
description = dividends[["Description"]]      # a frame dubbed "Description" with lines such as above                                    
ticker = description[description['Description'].str.contains('.NYSE')]
print(ticker)
```

Comment: Print `df.head(5).to_dict()` and add the output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the pattern of description, if you do not have a specific list of tickers and `split` the string:

```
df['ticker'] = df['description'].str.split('dividend ').str[-1].str.split().str[0]
```

or use a `regex` instead

```
df['ticker'] = df['description'].str.extract(r'(\b[A-Z]\w+\.[A-Z]\w+)')
```

---

To extract a `list` of tickers:

```
df['description'].str.extract(r'(\b[A-Z]\w+\.[A-Z]\w+)')[0].tolist()
-> ['AGNC.NASDAQ', 'BTI.NYSE', 'GAIN.NASDAQ', 'LTC.NYSE', 'MO.NYSE']
```

To avoid duplicates use `set()`

```
set(df['description'].str.extract(r'(\b[A-Z]\w+\.[A-Z]\w+)')[0].tolist())
-> {'AGNC.NASDAQ', 'BTI.NYSE', 'GAIN.NASDAQ', 'LTC.NYSE', 'MO.NYSE'}
```

##### Example

This will create an additional column with ticker in your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {17: '200 shares ExD 2022-09-21 PD 2022-09-30 dividend GAIN.NASDAQ 15.00 USD (0.075 per share) tax -2.25 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06',
18: '101 shares ExD 2022-09-21 PD 2022-09-30 dividend LTC.NYSE 19.19 USD (0.19 per share) tax -2.88 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06', 
19: '302 shares ExD 2022-09-29 PD 2022-10-12 dividend AGNC.NASDAQ 36.24 USD (0.12 per share) tax -5.44 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06',
20: '92 shares ExD 2022-07-07 PD 2022-08-22 dividend BTI.NYSE 60.31 USD (0.655523 per share) tax -0.00 USD (-0.0%) DivCntry GB fee amount -0.46 USD (0.005 per share)', 
21: '75 shares ExD 2022-09-14 PD 2022-10-11 dividend MO.NYSE 70.50 USD (0.94 per share) tax -10.58 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06'}

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), columns=['description'])
df['ticker'] = df['description'].str.extract(r'(\b[A-Z]\w+\.[A-Z]\w+)')

df[['ticker','description']]
```

##### Output

|  | ticker | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GAIN.NASDAQ | 200 shares ExD 2022-09-21 PD 2022-09-30 dividend GAIN.NASDAQ 15.00 USD (0.075 per share) tax -2.25 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06 |
| 1 | LTC.NYSE | 101 shares ExD 2022-09-21 PD 2022-09-30 dividend LTC.NYSE 19.19 USD (0.19 per share) tax -2.88 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06 |
| 2 | AGNC.NASDAQ | 302 shares ExD 2022-09-29 PD 2022-10-12 dividend AGNC.NASDAQ 36.24 USD (0.12 per share) tax -5.44 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06 |
| 3 | BTI.NYSE | 92 shares ExD 2022-07-07 PD 2022-08-22 dividend BTI.NYSE 60.31 USD (0.655523 per share) tax -0.00 USD (-0.0%) DivCntry GB fee amount -0.46 USD (0.005 per share) |
| 4 | MO.NYSE | 75 shares ExD 2022-09-14 PD 2022-10-11 dividend MO.NYSE 70.50 USD (0.94 per share) tax -10.58 USD (-15.000%) DivCntry US USIncmCode 06 |

Comment: And as a follow up, how should I write str.extract() parameters to get the amount of taxes paid? It is located between the words 'tax' and 'USD' a few letters to the right.

Comment: Happy to help - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus, We will notice it. - May also wanna check https://regex101.com/ to playaround a bit with regex.